# Do I need to get people to sign a waiver to include their content in my book?

Tags: self-publishing, legal, non-fiction, contracts

I am working on a book that will be based on the results of ten interview questions that I am asking of multiple well-known-in-their-field people.

Do I need to get these folks to sign a waiver or some sort of other legal document before I can publish their responses?

Maybe I don't *need* to, but is it wise to?

I'm self-publishing for what it is worth.

Comment: How extensive are the questions? How well-known are the people? How likely are they to complain? As far as any documentation required, ask a lawyer, not random self-selected people on-line.

Comment: As a fine point, a "waiver" is someone giving up their legal rights.  What you want is "permission" to use someone else's intellectual property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it is absolutely wise.  Any sorts of legal complications can arise and it's always best to be in the clear.  I wrote up a contract with a close friend of mine adapting her work (basically making me her agent as well as granting separate use of her characters).  Relationships and situations can change.

Comment: I think OP would have a hard time finding a publisher if the legalities weren't nailed down first.

Comment: @DavidThornley OP is self-publishing.  Though personally I wouldn't publish anything more formal than a blog without having contracts just like a traditional publisher would.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with El Cadejo, it is always wise to have a contract in place.  This covers you legally (and to some degree ethically) if:

- You have a falling out with one of your subjects who wants to pull their work.
- A subject doesn't like your interpretation of her/his words and claims you never had permission to use them.
- A publisher requires this in the future* but then you can't reach one of your subjects.
- Your book makes lots of money and a subject thinks some should go to her/him.
- A subject dies and her/his next of kin is not into the project or is so overwhelmed that s/he won't respond to your requests.

* Note: You may be self-publishing now but maybe the book will be reprinted or, even more likely, you may wish to submit some articles based on the larger book.

Always always cover your tuchis.